# SSH Permission denied between servers running bash script

Tags: server, bash, permissions, ssh

I am configuring access between servers but I am getting the access denied return message. Altogether I have 4 servers with Ubuntu Server 18.04.4 LTS installed and within the same IP range. They all have their key pairs installed. My problem occurs when I try to run a bash script where I access via ssh from one server to the other 3 to run some commands, and at this moment I get the message of access denied.
An important detail is that if I try to access another server via ssh running directly on the terminal I can access it normally.
I have already checked the ssh directories of all servers and all public keys are correctly distributed among all servers in the authorized-keys file.
I have tried some alternatives related to changing the /etc/ssh/sshd-config file, but I have not been successful either.
If anyone has any ideas to help, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: I Includes the OS version. This VMs are running over Openstack.

Comment: Have you checked the logs to see what SSH has to say about the failed logins?

Comment: try `ssh -vvv` for a detailed trace of the ssh transaction.